# sed -e '/pattern/ {d;n}'

Tags: sed

sed -e '/pattern/ {d;n}'

sed -e '/pattern/ {d}'

Are these two commands the same on Linux?
Is it meaningful to put n at the end?

From "man sed", I got :

> n N    Read/append the next line of input into the pattern space.

Actually, I read this line (u-boot helper.mk):

> ```
> sed -n -e '/.*\.u_boot_list[^ ]\+/ ! {d;n}' \
>       -e 's/.*\(\.u_boot_list[^ ]\+\).*$$$$/\1/' \
>       -e 's/\.[^\.]\+$$$$//' \
>       -e ':s /^.\+$$$$/ { p;s/^\(.*\)\.[^\.]*$$$$/\1/;b s }'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The two commands exist to serve two different (although seemingly similar) purposes. In your case, however, the "n" is redundant. Recall:

The "n" command will print out the current pattern space (unless the "-n" flag is used), empty the current pattern space, and read in the next line of input.

The "d" command deleted the current pattern space, reads in the next line, puts the new line into the pattern space, and aborts the current command, and starts execution at the first sed command. This is called starting a new "cycle."

This brief was taken from [the grymoire site](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html). You can read more about working with multiple lines [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51).